# Exclude/disable previously selected option from drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 drop-downs: Product, Batch and Storage

HTML:

```
    <div class="row div-1">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control product-id">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Product</option>
                <option value="1">Product One</option>
                <option value="2">Product Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control product-batch">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Batch</option>
                <option value="1">Batch One</option>
                <option value="2">Batch Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control product-storage">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Storage</option>
                <option value="1">Storage One</option>
                <option value="2">Storage Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row div-2">
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control product-id">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Product</option>
                <option value="1">Product One</option>
                <option value="2">Product Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control product-batch">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Batch</option>
                <option value="1">Batch One</option>
                <option value="2">Batch Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control product-storage">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select Storage</option>
                <option value="1">Storage One</option>
                <option value="2">Storage Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How to check if options are already selected based on 3 select options?

What I mean is if "Product One", "Batch One" and "Storage One" from div-1 is already selected and if I try to select same drop-down options in div-2, it should not allow to select again already selected options.

But can allow if I select "Product One", "Batch Two" and "Storage Two".

**In short same selected options cannot be repeated.**

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do this.  One way would be to have an event that triggers when an option is selected, and then disable that option in the other elements.

Comment: If there was a only one select element that would be easy to track previous select but I don't know how to do for multiple elements.

Comment: You don't have to track anything -- if a user selects option A, disable option A in all other selects.  If the user de-selects option A, then enable option A in all selects.  In other words, there is no "previous" to track.  The options are already disabled for the previous selected because you disabled them at the point when they were selected.

Comment: No, that was not my expected result. User can select option A again if other selected options are different from previous select. Please check example in my question.